# Grub is only a command line, and cant see windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I recently set up linux on my main machine, to be compatible with a research group I'm now working with, as a dual boot with windows 10. After instillation, grub comes up as a command line, and doesn't see either os.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) and I managed to boot into linux using the following code

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub> boot
```

subbing root for the correct directory, as well as the correct linux and initrd files.

The isue is that I have to enter this every time I boot the machine. I tried the code at the bottom of the page talking about "permanent repairs" but it didn't work. I also have no way as of now to get back to my windows partition.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Ubuntu , just as you described, and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub`. Reboot to test.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for Ubuntu 18+ and Windows 10:

The problem is that you BIOS is UEFI mode, whereas your ubuntu is loading the HDD as legacy mode.
You can confirm using the below command:

```
-d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"
```

Once confirmed, you need to convert Ubuntu into UEFI mode:
Note: Do not follow this procedure if your computer is already booting correctly. Use this procedure only if you believe you've accidentally installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and you want it to boot in UEFI/UEFI mode:

1. Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab.
2. If you do not see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, this means that your PC does not have any UEFI partition. In this case, exit Boot-Repair, then create an UEFI partition (see the "Creating an UEFI partition" paragraph above).
3. If you see a "Separate /boot/efi partition" line, tick it then click the "Apply" button.
4. Set up your BIOS so that it boots the HDD in UEFI mode (see the ""Set up the BIOS in UEFI or Legacy mode" paragraph above).

[image: Boot-Repair image]

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score -1):

I usually use a utility called Boot Repair. Here's the Linux Community page for Boot Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair